# Is there a way to disable IDE0005_gen warnings?

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

The following auto-generated .g.cs file has some unused usings and I'd like to silence warnings:

```
#pragma warning disable IDE0005
#pragma warning disable IDE0005_gen
using System;
```

However, neither `IDE0005` nor `IDE0005_gen` do work:

[image]

Also tried in .editorconfig but without success:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.ide0005.severity = none
dotnet_diagnostic.ide0005_gen.severity = none
```

Is there a way to disable IDE warnings in auto-generated files?

Comment: I would try via .editorconfig.

Comment: Just tried, that doesn't work unfortunately, I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: [Remove unnecessary using directives (IDE0005)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0005)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS 2022 (.NET 6), to disable [IDE0005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0005) do one of the following:

**Option 1**:

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select <project name> Properties
- Expand **Build**
- Click **General**
- Under "Implicit global usings", uncheck **Enable implicit global usings to be declared by the project SDK**

---

**Option 2**:

In <project name>.csproj (ex: WinFormsApp1.csproj), change

**From**:

```
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
```

**To**:

```
<ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
```

**WinFormsApp1.csproj**:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**Resources**:

- [Welcome to C# 10](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-csharp-10/#:%7E:text=Implicit%20usings%20let%20you%20include,them%20available%20throughout%20your%20project.)

Comment: Surprisingly, that worked out!